# Bootstrap put container in container fluid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make two different column background, for that I set container-fluid, and make two columns, and make another row.. but It don't want to work.

[I need like this (PHOTO)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKIJq.png)

Here is my code

```
    <section id="mid">
    <div class="container-fluid mid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 left">
                        <div class="container">
                            <h2>Inovative macaroons</h2>
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x media-object">
                                            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x bg"></i>
                                            <i class="fa fa-tag fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-body">
                                    <h3 class="media-heading">Best Prices</h3>
                                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada et.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 right">
                        <h2> Specials</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

In "left" css I made white BG, and In right I made pink.

Answer (score 0):

Use flex css to achieve this. If i am understanding you right, you want both columns to have same height as the one column with the largest height due to text.

Add the following css in your code

```
.flex-row {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .flex-row > [class*='col-'] {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Then apply the flex-row to the row containing the left and right colomns

```
<div class="row flex-row">
                <div class="col-md-6 left">
                    <div class="container">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: look, I want my conent to bee in container (between red lines).

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle of your screen and share and i will help with the fix. Probably you need to explicitly set the display property of the flex box container to inline-block.

Comment: If i am understanding this right then here is example to achieve what you are asking. http://codepen.io/Nasir_T/pen/GjPdmE    Hope this helps.